# simple tkinter question - button command (display other text on click)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

i've just started learning tkinter for python, and i'm trying to get the button to change its text when it's clicked on.

this seems like a very simple question, but i can't find any answers. the code i'm using at the moment doesn't work - when the window opens, it displays 'clicked!' as a label above the button immediately, before i've clicked on the button.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click():
    label = Label(root, text = 'clicked!')
    label.pack()

button = Button(root, text='click me', command = click())

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change an existing button's text (or some other option), you can call its [`config()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method and pass it keyword arguments with new values in them. Note that when constructing the `Button` only pass it the **name** of the callback function — i.e. don't call it).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click():
    button.config(text='clicked!')

button = Button(root, text='click me', command=click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `command = click()` to the `Button` constructor. This way, Python *executes* `click`, then passes its return value to `Button`. To pass the function itself, remove the parentheses - `command = click`.